# I haven't given you much/a lot of

Tags: word-usage

I was having dinner, but I couldn't finish it all up. So my mom said:

> Eat it up, I haven't **given you much/a lot.**
>
> Eat it up, **it wasn't too much.**

Something like soup:

> Finish it, I haven't given you **much/a lot of**  soup.

And about Indian dal (semi-solid)

> Finish it, I haven't given you **much/a lot of** dal.

And about something solid, will it still be the same?

I don't know the best way to describe it.......

Comment: These sentences are made up by you. So these types of questions end up being about correcting or editing. You might start by checking: finish and finish up. Solid or liquid has nothing to do with these questions, it seems. Also, **eat it up** is an odd thing to say here. It is usually not in an "order" but in a description: The food was so good he ate it all up. I think your question is really about: a lot of food/much food.

Comment: Yes @Lambie this question is about "a lot of food/much food". So what do you think about the sentences (much/ a lot) (I know the language describing the question isn't up to the mark, but I'm trying to get better at it.....)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would be the same.
"Finish it, I haven't given you much/ a lot of meat" is a perfectly acceptable sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> With regards to something solid, would it still be the same?

Yes, the same phrase would apply to liquid, semi-solid and solid food items.  The state of matter of the food does not affect the phrase.

> How would you put **"much"** or **"a lot"** in a sentence – *"I haven't given you much/a lot"* or *"I haven't given you much/a lot of soup/vegetables"*?

In casual speech, I would simply leave the phrase hanging, without specifying the actual noun.  Consider:

- *"I haven't given you much."*
- *"I haven't given you a lot."*
- *"I haven't given you* that *much."*

While all the above are valid, I would most-likely phrase like the last option—with emphasis on **that**—as it subtly delineates between the speaker's *opposition to the listener's opinion* that they have been given too much, and not giving as much for a specific *reason* (e.g. due to the listener being on a strict diet, or the cost/availability of the food).

- *"I haven't given you much, because I know you are on a diet."*
- *"I haven't given you a lot, because I can't afford to."*

I do note that injecting and emphasising **that** is still applicable to the above sentences but, in that case, it is more likely a passive apology (becuase you are unable to give more) than the encouragement to eat more:

- *"[I'm sorry,] I haven't given you that much, because I know you are on a diet."*
- *"[I'm sorry,] I haven't given you that much, because I can't afford to."*

If you felt that you *needed* to specify exactly what food you had deliberately reduced, I would also use **many** for countable food items.  This gives you options, such as:

- *"I haven't given you* that *much soup."*
- *"I haven't given you* that *much dal."*
- *"I haven't given you* that *much meat."* (as per [Eli786's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/219165/97730))
- *"I haven't given you* that ***many*** vegetables."
- *"I haven't given you* that ***many*** peas."

...but you could substitute **a lot**, in most cases:

- *"I haven't given you a lot of soup."*
- *"I haven't given you a lot of dal."*
- *"I haven't given you a lot of meat."*
- *"I haven't given you a lot of vegetables."*
- *"I haven't given you a lot of peas."*

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to repeat questions that are not grammatical. How does that help the poster?

Comment: @Lambie : I understand your sentiment, but I'm not sure how I improve the answer, in this case.  Those were the questions asked and the context that was given (which I've taken to transcribing in my answers because they keep disappearing from the comments).  I *believe* I have understood the OP's intent (as have you), and I'm willing to give a little grammatical leeway to a question from a clearly non-native speaker.

Comment: I think it is useful to correct mistakes.

Comment: @Lambie : Agreed but, bar one missing double-quote (which I will fix), I'm not seeing any drastic mistakes in the two quoted questions.  I might consider changing "about" to "with regards to" and "will" to "would", but there's nothing there I wouldn't forgive in spoken, casual English, and I don't want to confuse the issue any more than the stuff about solids and semi-solids already does...